# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

**This index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ActionSheetIOS,
  CameraRoll,
  ListView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';

const util=require('util');
import Thumbnail from './App/Thumbnail';
import MaxImage from './App/MaxImage';
import Router from './App/Router';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
export default class PrinterApp extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

         <ScrollView style={styles.ScrollContainer}>
       <View style={styles.container}>

          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
          <Thumbnail style={styles.thumbnail}  url="http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg"/>
         </View>
       </ScrollView>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ScrollContainer:{
    flex:1,
  },
  container:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    flexWrap:'wrap',
  },
  thumbnail:{
    margin:2,
    width:(Dimensions.get('window').width)/3,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems: 'center',      
      }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PrinterApp', () => PrinterApp);
```

**This is Thumbnail.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';
import ResponsiveImage from 'react-native-responsive-image';
import MaxImage from './MaxImage';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

 class Thumbnail extends React.Component {
  press(url)
  {
     alert("button pressed"+{url});
     this.props.navigation.navigate('MaxImge');
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
      var url=this.props.url;
       var width=(Dimensions.get('window').width/3)+13;
       const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.press.bind(url)}>
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center',padding:2}}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                    <ResponsiveImage source={{uri:url}} initWidth={width} initHeight="138"/>
                </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>


    );
  }
}

export const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Thumbnail },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Thumbnail', () => SimpleApp);
```

**This is MaxImage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import ResponsiveImage from 'react-native-responsive-image';
import Button from 'react-native-button';


 class MaxImage extends Component {
   static navigationOptions={
     title:'MaxImage'
   };
  render() {
       var url=this.props.url;
       var width=(Dimensions.get('window').width)+48;
       var height=(Dimensions.get('window').height);
    return (
       <View>
        <Text>
          HI!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  getPrint()
  {

  }
  getBlock()
  {

  }
}

module.exports=MaxImage;
```

What I am trying to do is when the app launches it should show the photos in Grid View and when some clicks on a particular Thumbnail it should show a zoom Image with some options.

could someone help?. I have tried each and every solution available on various sites but I couldn't resolve this issue.
And please someone suggest me some good tutorial of react-navigation.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem (note the "minimal"), using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Even if you have posted lot of codes here, your problem is not yet cleared. Please update your question.

Comment: @LibinCJacob basically I want to implement stack navigator on Thumbnail component and when it clicked it should load MaxImage.js Component

Comment: Did you read the error message? It has ... a message for you, it, with the devtools tells pretty exact what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Try to console log props and check if you have navigation in it. If it is not there then you will have to check how you are adding these pages in your navigation.